# Botão avançar e voltar ajax

Tags: javascript

Preciso de ajuda para fazer um botão de avançar e voltar o mês de uma lista de aniversariantes. Os dados serão enviados via POST para uma classe que faz a consulta. A parte do `PHP` está ok. Preciso adaptar o `JavaScript`.

**PHP**

```
$data = date('Y-m-d');

$data_explode = explode("-", $data);

$dia = $data_explode[2];
$mes = $data_explode[1];
$ano = $data_explode[0];


$v_mes = substr($mes, 0, 2); //voltar mes
$novo_mes = (int) $mes - 1; //avancar mes


$botoes_mes = '<div class="medium-2 columns float-left">
                    <a id="#action-aniver" rel="' . $v_mes . '"><i class="fi-arrow-left"></i></a></div>
                   <div class="medium-8 columns float-center">
                      <h4 class="text-center">' . $mes . '</h4>
                   </div>
                   <div class="medium-2 columns">
                     <a id="#action-aniver" rel="' . $novo_mes . '"><i class="fi-arrow-right float-right"></i></a>
                   </div>';
```

**Classe Ajax:**

```
case 'aniversario':

$char = $_POST['val'];
$body = '';

$dados = connection::select("SELECT * from aniversarios where MONTH(data_usuario) = '" . $char . "'");

foreach ($dados as $reg) {

         $body .= '<p>' . $reg['nome'] . '</p>';

}

retorno = $body;


break;
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#action-aniver').click(function () {
        var chars = (this.value);
        $.post(URL + 'Ajax/aniversario', {val: chars}, function (busca) {
            $('#aniver-ajax').html(busca);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Qual é o problema que você está tendo?

Comment: Não funciona o código. Na verdade eu tentei fazer. Mas não consegui. Acredito que o problema seja na função do javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa adaptar algumas coisas em seu código, mas mais importante que resolver esse único problema, é você entender melhor os conceitos de `client-side` e `server-side`, pois claramente você misturou algumas coisas que são impossíveis de acontecer utilizando essas linguagens. Mas vamos ao que interessa, faça as seguintes adaptações:

**HTML**

```
<div class="medium-2 columns float-left">
    <a id="#action-aniver-prev">
        <i class="fi-arrow-left"></i>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="medium-8 columns float-center">
    <h4 class="text-center" id="month"></h4>
    <div id="aniver-ajax">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="medium-2 columns">
    <a id="#action-aniver-next">
        <i class="fi-arrow-right float-right"></i>
    </a>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="current-month" value="0"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    function changeMonth(month){
       var months = [
           "JAN",
           "FEV",
           "MAR",
           "ABR",
           "MAI",
           "JUN",
           "JUL",
           "AGO",
           "SET",
           "OUT",
           "NOV",
           "DEZ"
       ]; 

       $("#month").html(months[month-1]);
    }

    $(function(){
        $('#action-aniver-next').click(function () {
            var chars = $('[name="current-month"]').val();
            chars++;
            if(chars > 12)
                chars = 1;

            changeMonth(chars);

            $('[name="current-month"]').val(chars);

            $.post(URL + 'Ajax/aniversario', {val: chars}, function (busca) {
                $('#aniver-ajax').html(busca);
            });
        });

        $('#action-aniver-prev').click(function () {
            var chars = $('[name="current-month"]').val();
            chars--;
            if(chars < 1)
                chars = 12;

            changeMonth(chars);

            $('[name="current-month"]').val(chars);

            $.post(URL + 'Ajax/aniversario', {val: chars}, function (busca) {
                $('#aniver-ajax').html(busca);
            });
        });

        $('#action-aniver-next').trigger('click');
    });
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho cara. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Como posso colocar o nome dos meses?

Comment: Creio que isso resolva

Comment: Parou de voltar o meses, só avança

Comment: Quando clico no botão voltar, ele avança

Comment: Não seria chars-- no #action-aniver-prev ?

Comment: Exatamente, nesse ponto estava errado desde a o começo...hehe

Comment: rs, valeu pela ajuda.